# Should every part of a web app be a react component?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-fullstack

I haven't touched React in over 2 years, and a bit confused looking back at my old code. For example, if I were to build an instagram clone, would I utilize html templates and inject javascript as such as

```
<div id="reactEntry">
    Loading ...
</div>
```

for the login page, profile page, etc.
and use react components for main logic? for example, dynamically rendering posts and comments?

Or would it be smarter to make everything a react component-- login page, profile page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

would it be smarter to make everything a react component-- login page, profile page, etc. - yes. As you don't need to rely much on other libraries and can use routing between pages. Also, there is performance benefit for a fully react app.
Having other components along with react component would not cause any harm as long as you don't dom manipulate the react component.

Answer (score 0):

> Or would it be smarter to make everything a react component-- login
>   page, profile page, etc.

There are benefits of using react components over the traditional multi-page web apps.

- Since most react apps are Single Page Applications(SPA), hence they are fetched once, and then virtual dom handles the rendering of various components. This is **faster** than the tree-based document rendering.
- Components are re-usable. Say you need a `Document upload form` - consisting of a drag and drop file field and an upload button. You could simply create a component, and keep using it at multiple places. All components have their internal logic, which makes it easier to manipulate and define them. Such an approach ensures a consistent app look and facilitates codebase maintenance and growth.
- Plugins like [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) can handle page transitions, by using its navigational components. You could do partial renders too, giving you a faster UI/UX experience than rendering the entire pages.